# LINQ to Stored XML

Tags: linq-to-sql

Does anybody know the status of [this](http://oakleafblog.blogspot.com/2007/12/linq-to-xsd-redux-and-linq-to-stored.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for LINQ to XSD has been released to Codeplex at http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/ and effectively ending the development on that project.

LINQ to SQL serializes XML data type columns into XElement types. However, don't expect to see L2S to be extended to support translating LINQ to XML subqueries into the matching XQuery in the database. The Entity Framework team may add such functionality at some point in the future, but it's not on their radar at this point either.